# scripting logic : matching patterns

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to figure out regex/scripting logic to parse something out like this;

```
RAW DATA
 {CLNDSDB=MedGen:OMIM:SNOMED_CT;CLNDSDBID=C0432243:271640:254100000}


Here, the value is; 
     MedGen = C0432243
     OMIM = 271640
     SNOMED_CT = 254100000 

Result: 271640
```

I am envisaging a convoluted if-else loop to get the result. Just wanted to know if there any simple way of get the same result. Much appreciate your answers.

Comment: Why OMIM is not 271640?

Comment: Sorry you were right... just my copy paste gone wrong

Comment: In my opinion the simplest approach is probably to get the `CLNDSDB` and `CLNDSDBID` values, to split them on `:` and to pair elements with matching indexes together.

Comment: So something like this: hash[:test] = hash['CLNDSDB'].split(':')[0].gsub('OMIM','') and delim_index = str.rindex(':')

Comment: Is your question formatted correctly? It's difficult to tell what is data, and what is expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this: (assuming there is always three fields)

```
(?<=[=:])(?<key>[^:;]+)(?=[:=;](?:[^:;=]+[=;:]){3}(?<val>[^:]+))
```

The idea is to capture the field values inside a lookahead assertion so as not to be interfering with overlapping substrings.

However, there is probably a cleaner way that uses successive split.

Comment: That's a rad regex! It doesn't get the correct last value for me ([see here](http://regex101.com/r/fU8cR6)), because in the last case you use the first `(?:[^:=]+[=:])` to skip `CLNDSDBID=` instead of skipping a value. I believe you can fix it by replacing `(?:[^:=]+[=:]){2}(?<val>[^:]+)` with `(?:[^:=;]+[=:;]){3}(?<val>[^:}]+)` (don't forget to add the `}` at the end)

Comment: @Robin: You are right, I was working on it (sometime rubular takes a lot of time to refresh). It is corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell from the question whether the input string is two lines or one:

```
str = 'RAW DATA
 {CLNDSDB=MedGen:OMIM:SNOMED_CT;CLNDSDBID=C0432243:271640:254100000}
'
```

or

```
str = '{CLNDSDB=MedGen:OMIM:SNOMED_CT;CLNDSDBID=C0432243:271640:254100000}'
```

but, in either case I'd use a simple pattern:

```
str = '{CLNDSDB=MedGen:OMIM:SNOMED_CT;CLNDSDBID=C0432243:271640:254100000}'
medgen, omim, snomed_ct = str.match(/(\w+):(\w+):(\w+)}/).captures

medgen # => "C0432243"
omim # => "271640"
snomed_ct # => "254100000"
```

Here's [the pattern at Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/sW0LzR74RY).

> I am envisaging a convoluted if-else loop to get the result.

Well, don't do that. Most programming solutions are surprisingly simple, so start simple. As you learn, your programming toolbox will grow as you become familiar with new ways of doing things, and you'll find certain tools are more useful for certain tasks. Still, always start from "simple", get the basics working, then carefully add to handle the corner cases.

In this case, when using a regular expression, it's important to look for landmarks in the string that you can use to locate your target text. In this case the trailing '`}`' is usable, so I wrote three simple captures to find `\w` strings separated by `:`.

Comment: Hi You are right, I am using your method of encapsulating string value and its working.